# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: NamedFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I hope many of the you guys encounter this issue. Scenario is very simple, I have one activity with a ViewPager. In that ViewPager, I need to display two fragments or one based on the logic. Therefore, I have created a ViewPagerAdapter from FragmentPagerAdapter and dynamically adding fragment base on the condition. However, it is not working and giving below error,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: NamedFragment{2c7b548 #0 id=0x7f0e0097 android:switcher:2131624087:0}
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1669)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:720)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2303)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2132)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2092)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1969)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:620)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5952)
                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18805)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Please someone help me to resolve it.

Thank  you

Comment: you can use viewpager2 to solve this problem [see the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59393854/2383176)

Answer (score 0):

As it says,you add the same fragment twice in the same content layout.
You should use replace() instead of add() to avoid this.

Comment: Hi, I called only one time my method so I am sure I am not adding twice, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not add fragment manually to viewpager, Instead of using FragmentPagerAapter use FragmentStatePagerAdapter and then use notifydatasetchange() method of adapter to dynamically alter the number of fragments that are displayed by viewpager.
I will not give you the code but direction

Comment: "Therefore, I have created a ViewPagerAdapter from FragmentPagerAdapter and dynamically adding fragment base on the condition" to ViewPagerAdapter.  I am doing exactly as you have mentioned but still I am getting this error. why

Comment: Did you use notifydatasetchange?

Comment: check this link https://medium.com/inloop/adventures-with-fragmentstatepageradapter-4f56a643f8e0#.vs2ua2izs

Comment: Thank you, I am not using notifyDatasetChanged because it is not need for my case as I am using FragmentPagerAdapter and set fragments before set to ViewPager.