# Fragment already added with FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I have an Activity with ViewPager and this ViewPager holds 3 fragments.

I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter to create the Fragments, like this:

```
    class ViewPagerUser(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private val matchDetails: MatchDetails, private val context: Context) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    // Returns total number of pages
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return NUM_ITEMS
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return FragmentDetailMatchInfoUser.newInstance(matchDetails)
            1 -> return FragmentDetailMatchParticipantsUser.newInstance(matchDetails)
            2 -> return FragmentDetailMatchWall.newInstance(matchDetails)
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return context.getString(R.string.info)
            1 -> return context.getString(R.string.player)
            2 -> return context.getString(R.string.wall)
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val NUM_ITEMS = 3
    }
}
```

This is how I use it

```
    if (matchDetails != null && (matchDetails.cancelled!! || screenType == App.USER || matchDetails.matchStatus == 40 || matchDetails.matchStatus == 50)) {
        adapterViewPager = ViewPagerUser(supportFragmentManager, matchDetails, this)
    } else if (screenType == App.ORGANIZER) {
        adapterViewPager = ViewPagerOrganizer(supportFragmentManager, matchDetails!!, this)
    }

    viewPager?.adapter = adapterViewPager

    viewPager?.offscreenPageLimit = 3
```

I thought this was the best way to handle Fragments inside the ViewPager, but I'm getting many reports on Crashlytics of "Fragment already added" as you can see in the log bellow:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added: FragmentDetailMatchInfoUser{b17d64 #0 id=0x7f090551 android:switcher:2131297617:0}
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.addOp(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(Unknown Source)
   at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6087)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19883)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2293)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1384)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1637)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1272)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6408)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

I went through almost every question related to this problem here in Stackoverflow and the suggested answers couldn't help me... The bug always comes back.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: By this error means, you are trying to add fragment that is already is in stack. Are you trying to add fragment outside viewpager ?

Comment: No, I do not call addFragment explicitly.

Comment: Try to add this `if(yourFragment.isAdded()){ return; }` where you are getting error.

Comment: you can user viewpager2 to solve this problem [see the approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59393854/2383176)

Comment: @javadroid Why viewpager2 could solve this problem? Any article or source code please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This reports may be caused because you are creating new instance of a fragment every time ViewPager asks for a fragment.

You should try creating fragment instances when you create your ViewPager:

```
class ViewPagerUser(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private val matchDetails: MatchDetails, private val context: Context) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

private val fragmentDetailMatchInfoUser = FragmentDetailMatchInfoUser.newInstance(matchDetails)
private val fragmentDetailMatchParticipantsUser = FragmentDetailMatchParticipantsUser.newInstance(matchDetails)
private val fragmentDetailMatchWall = FragmentDetailMatchWall.newInstance(matchDetails)

    // Returns total number of page
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return NUM_ITEMS
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return fragmentDetailMatchInfoUser
            1 -> return fragmentDetailMatchParticipantsUser
            2 -> return fragmentDetailMatchWall
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return context.getString(R.string.info)
            1 -> return context.getString(R.string.player)
            2 -> return context.getString(R.string.wall)
            else -> return null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val NUM_ITEMS = 3
    }
 }
```

I had similar problem and it helped me. Hope it will help you too.

Comment: Tried this, sent to production but the error showed again in Crashlytics =(

Comment: Are you sure this was the only thing you did to solve the problem?

Comment: How is this code different from the code in the question?

Comment: @Mitch this code initialized the page fragments when the ViewPagerAdapter is created. The other code initialized the page fragments every time `getItem` is called, thus initializing a new fragment every time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [isAdded()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isAdded()) to check whether or not the fragment is detached from the activity.

```
if (!mFragmentDetailMatchInfoUser.isAdded()) {
    return FragmentDetailMatchInfoUser.newInstance(matchDetails);
}
```

and also for the two fragments.

Comment: I should combine your answer with Andrey's answer? (the answer below)

Comment: I don't think so.what If you have too many fragments?.It's not the best practice.also, His answer has nothing to do with your problem.your problem is that you are trying to attach a fragment which was already added.you only need to check before adding it.so is enough I think to solve your problem.

Comment: But, if you see my opening question, I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter, where I don't hold a reference of the fragments... I return a new one Everytime is asked. In your answer, you tell me to check if a reference of the fragment (which is suggested to be create by Andrey's answer) is not added, am I wrong?

Comment: `Fragment`s are Large objects.you will wast memory.see this quote from the developer's  website.


>  The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible. This can result in using a significant amount of memory since fragment instances can hold on to an arbitrary amount of state

Comment: If I do what I'm going to waste memory?

Comment: you will keep a reference to your fragments inside the memory which are heavy objects as the quote says. that's why they created `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to handle this issue.

Comment: Got it! But I still don't understand what should I do to solve my problem, in your opinion.

Comment: It's not a relevant answer considering the question! This would be an answer if the question was not about `FragmentPagerAdapter` for `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was resolved by adding a 2nd parameter to the FragmentPagerAdapter like this:

class ViewPagerUser(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private val matchDetails: MatchDetails, private val context: Context) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {...}

More:
FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) is deprecated, you must be change to FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) and the problem will be solved.